# Transparency using GLSL Android Opengl es 2.0

Tags: android, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I am working on opengl es 2.0 for android application. I have a model for which 
i apply texture. I do this by using the below shaders. Its a simple shader.

In the below shader when the texture file is transparent at some places I get a 
black color. Instead I want to find the places where it is transparent and give a particular color like RGB(0.6,0.7,0.3). Please let me know how to modify the below shader to get this in my model.

```
protected static final String mVShader = 

    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
    "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
    "attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;\n" +
    "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +

    "void main() {\n" +
    "   gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
    "   vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;\n" +
    "}\n";

protected static final String mFShader = 

    "precision mediump float;\n" +

    "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
    "uniform sampler2D uTexture0;\n" +

    "void main() {\n" +
    "   gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture0, vTextureCoord);\n" +
    "}\n";
```

Comment: How do you define places "when the texture file is transparent"? Do you mean having an alpha of zero? Can't you just put that particular color into the texture at those points?

Comment: Yes i mean the alpha is zero. But i want to put different colors in that place. So I want to do it via code. Please let me know your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the easiest thing would just be to check the texture color's alpha and output a different color depending on this:

```
void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(uTexture0, vTextureCoord);
    gl_FragColor = (color.a > 0.1) ? color : vec4(0.6, 0.7, 0.3, 1.0);
}
```

Of course you can adapt this threshold, but using just `0.0` might not work due to precision issues. Dynamic branching in the fragment shader might not be the best idea performance-wise, but if you say you cannot just change the texture because the color may change, this will be the easiest way.

If the color change is  persistent over a large number of frames, you maybe also could create a temporary texture, which contains the changed color in the transparent regions. This can be achieved easily on the GPU using the above shader and just rendering into this temporary texture (using [FBOs](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html)) instead of the display framebuffer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Yes you are right that my application will be faster if i create a temporary texture as the dynamic color set will be retained for several frames. But I am not sure how to do create a temporary texture from a FBO. Sorry I am pretty new to shaders. Please let me know with a link or sample code that can help me. Thank you very much for the efforts.

Comment: @Vinodtiru Now you don't actually create a temporary texture each time you change the color. You create this texture once at the same time you create the original texture, and also in the same way, except that you don't put any image data into it (you call `glTexImage2d(..., NULL)` or whatever equivalent in your language). Then whenever the color changes you create the image data by rendering directly into this texture using an [FBO](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html) and the above mentioned shader (the link is for desktop, but should work similar in ES, if FBOs are supported).

Comment: @Vinodtiru If FBOs aren't supported, you can also use `glCopyTexSubImage2D`, which copies an image from the framebuffer (you rendered into) into a texture. This will cost you a copy, but it's only a GPU-to-GPU copy.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will definitely try it out. :)